# использование библиотеки re

Tags: python

Часть кода парсера с использованием BeautifulSoup

```
'цена': item.find(class_='snippet-price').get_text(separator=' ').strip()

 .replace(' ', '')
 .replace('.', '')
 .replace('₽', '')
```

Задача заменить повторяющиеся ".replace" регулярным выражением:

```
import re

'цена': item.find(class_='snippet-price').get_text(separator=' ').strip().re.sub(r"[ .₽]", "")
```

Возвращает ошибку:

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 're'**

Comment: `"цена": re.sub(r"[ .₽]", "", item.find(class_='snippet-price').get_text(separator=' ').strip())`

Comment: спасибо, работает, я не мог понять почему re не принимает str

Comment: чтобы не создавать дополнительный вопрос, подскажите пожалуйста как обрезать url в аналогичной конструкции, после знака '?': 'урл': HOST + item.find(class_='snippet-link').get('href')

Comment: `.split('?', 1)[0]`

Comment: а как можно прочитать данную конструкцию? всё работает, но не могу понять логику